# Google Cloud ML-Engine online predictions error: feed a value for placeholder tensor which is already included

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

I have been facing the following error for several days, and still can't come out with a solution:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'decoder_input' with dtype float and shape [?,?,1]
>
> [[node decoder_input (defined at /Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ml_sdk/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py:210) ]]
>
> (Error code: 2)

I trained my `tf.keras.Model` (Python 3.6, Tensorflow 1.13.1) and exported it successfully to Google Cloud ML-engine.

By running `saved_model_cli show --all --dir=trainer/predict-dir/1552642125` I get:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['decoder_input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, 1)
        name: decoder_input_1:0
    inputs['encoder_input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, 1)
        name: encoder_input_1:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['reg_sequence_prediction'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, 1)
        name: reg_sequence_prediction/BiasAdd:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

My `instances.json` file is:

`{"decoder_input": [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]], "encoder_input": [[-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672], [-1.1672]]}`

As you can see, I included both of the necessary input values, but still I keep receiving the very same error.

I didn't include any Dropout nor Regularization layers, the model is a simple seq2seq keras Model with RNNs and GRUCells.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Solved using ```tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn()``` rather than ```tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver()```. Hope it helps